# How to convert Row values into Column Headers in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Here is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM  client_data where RefID =27
```

and `Value` column's datatype is `nvarchar`.

TABLE is like below...

```
AnalysisID  RefID        RefColumn               Value

44      27  Reporting_Currency      EUR
44      27  Reporting_Currency      EUR
44      27  Reporting_Currency      USD
44      27  Reporting_Group         0001
44      27  Reporting_Group         0001
44      27  Reporting_Group         0002
44      27  Reporting_Language      EN
44      27  Reporting_Language      EN
44      27  Reporting_Language      DE
65      27  Company_Code            -   
65      27  MANDT               -   
65      27  Reporting_Currency      -
```

Expected RESULT:

```
Analysisid       Reporting_Currency   Reporting_Group  Reporting_Language  

44          EUR     0001          EN
44          EUR     0001          EN
44          USD     0002          DE
65          -
```

I tried with `PIVOT` but couldn't succeed.

How can I do this?

Regards,
Jn

Answer (score 1):

First thing: There's a major problem with your data - as there's nothing to tie what you've defined as being separate rows together as such, other than the ordering of the result set. You should have a column in there called "item" that links these together.

That said I've imposed an ordering in the following SQL example:

```
;WITH CTE_TestData as (

select AnalysisID = 44,  RefID=27, RefColumn = 'Reporting_Currency', Value='EUR'
union all select 44,      27,  'Reporting_Currency',     'EUR'
union all select 44,      27,  'Reporting_Currency',     'USD'
union all select 44,      27,  'Reporting_Group',         '0001'
union all select 44,      27,  'Reporting_Group',         '0001'
union all select 44,      27,  'Reporting_Group',         '0002'
union all select 44,      27,  'Reporting_Language',      'EN'
union all select 44,      27,  'Reporting_Language',      'EN'
union all select 44,     27,   'Reporting_Language',      'DE'
union all select 65,      27,  'Company_Code',            null
union all select 65,      27,  'MANDT',               null
union all select 65,     27,  'Reporting_Currency',      null

)

select AnalysisID, Reporting_Currency, Reporting_Group, Reporting_Language
from (
    select *, rowno = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY refid, analysisid, RefColumn Order By refid, analysisid, refcolumn)
    from
        CTE_TestData t
    ) unpvt
    PIVOT (min(value) FOR RefColumn in ([Reporting_Currency], [Reporting_Group], [Reporting_Language])) pvt
```

Returns:

```
AnalysisID  Reporting_Currency  Reporting_Group Reporting_Language
44          EUR                 0001            EN
44          USD                 0002            EN
44          EUR                 0001            DE
65          NULL                NULL            NULL
```